# puppet: Syntax error at 'target'; expected '}' - parsing error

Tags: puppet, nagios

Syntax error while parsing puppet resource.

```
    class nagios::export {
      @@nagios_host { $::fqdn:
        address       => $::ipaddress,
        use           => "linux-server",
        check_command => 'check-host-alive!3000.0,80%!5000.0,100%!10',
        hostgroups    => 'all-servers',
        target        => "/etc/nagios/resource.d/host_${::fqdn}.cfg"
      }


    @@nagios_service { "check_ping_${hostname}":
         check_command => "check-host-alive!100.0,20%!500.0,60%",
         use => "generic-service",
         host_name => "$fqdn",
         notification_period => "24x7",
         #target => "/etc/nagios/resource.d/service_${::fqdn}.cfg"
         service_description => "${hostname}_check_ping"
         target => "/etc/nagios/resource.d/service_${::fqdn}.cfg"
  }
}
```

When I run puppet apply , following error is seen..

[root@ip-10-172-161-25 manifests]# puppet apply export.pp  --noop

```
Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at 'target'; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/modules/nagios/manifests/export.pp:28 on node ip-10-172-161-25.us-west-1.compute.internal
```

Comment: Missing comma after `service_description` line

Comment: Thanks, comma worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class nagios::export {
  @@nagios_host { $::fqdn:
    address       => $::ipaddress,
    use           => "linux-server",
    check_command => 'check-host-alive!3000.0,80%!5000.0,100%!10',
    hostgroups    => 'all-servers',
    target        => "/etc/nagios/resource.d/host_${::fqdn}.cfg",
  }


@@nagios_service { "check_ping_${hostname}":
     check_command => "check-host-alive!100.0,20%!500.0,60%",
     use => "generic-service",
     host_name => "$fqdn",
     notification_period => "24x7",
     #target => "/etc/nagios/resource.d/service_${::fqdn}.cfg",
     service_description => "${hostname}_check_ping",
     target => "/etc/nagios/resource.d/service_${::fqdn}.cfg",
 }
}
```

Was just a few missing commas at the end.

I generally always finish with a comma on the last line. It's not needed, but catches gotcha's that happen when you add an extra line to the end.